# Can't the array pointer be distributed some space in other functions as argument

Tags: c, arrays

[Code](http://codepad.org/tOKdqElc)
Here is my code..
I can run it on VS2012, but there are some errors on code::blocks..
What caused it ?
It seems "**matrix" doesn't get space in the "Input_Number" function..
So the array pointer can't be distributed some space in other functions as argument,isn't it?
And how can i do ?
Thank u!!

Comment: Can you run it or there are errors?

Comment: What type of errors are you getting?

Comment: It's not the root cause of your problems, but [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20049823/edit) and post your code here. External Links are discouraged. Also, post any errors that you come across

Comment: You don't need the "conio.h" include...it compiles (and run) just fine with gcc (linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the value returned by `malloc()` the copy of `matrix` which is local to `Input_Number()`.

C passes (also) pointers by value, so the assignment is **not** reflected by the value of `matrix` declared in the `main()` which calls `Input_Number()`.

To fix this you could change:

```
int Input_Number(double **matrix, int *row, int *column)
```

to become:

```
double ** Input_Number(double **matrix, int *row, int *column)
{
```

and start it this way:

```
  if (NULL == matrix)
  {
    matrix = (double **) malloc (sizeof (double *) * *row) ;
  }
```

and end it this way

```
  return matrix;
}
```

Finally adjust the way it is called to become:

```
matrix = Input_Number(matrix, &row, &column);
```

Comment: uhh..thank u..but why are there two different running results between VS and code::blocks

Comment: because code::blocks is using gcc as C compiler and VS is using there own compiler as... well ... pseudo C compiler. And each compiler treats source code in a different way ;) So if your code is not absolutly well defined, the results are allowed to be different.

Comment: What do you consider "*running*"?

Comment: if i enter any numbers,code::blocks always prints "-0.000000" And VS prints the correct numbers..

Comment: The code is fine. codebocks is doing something wrong, or is used wrong.

Comment: ahhh...i had found the problem..it seems "%lf" isn't a part of clang standard..And the version of my gcc is 4.7.1 which isn't support "lf"..so i change it by "%f", and now it runs perfectly